# TYPO 3 : filter category by parent and pid issue

Tags: php, typo3

I want to display parents categories in first, and display sub categories of a category after clicking on it.

For it, I made a query to filter by pid and id of the parent (findByPidAndParent) but I have an error "Unknown column 'sys_category.pid_and_parent' in 'where clause'"

I don't know why I have this error, I made individual filters by pid and parents, and they work but with two filter, I have this error

I'm using typo3 system category.

There is some code :

```
public function listAction($parentId = null, $pageId = null)
    {
        //pageID
        $currentPid = $GLOBALS['TSFE']->id;
        // storagePid
        $myStoragePid = $this->settings['storagePid'];
               $categories = $this->categorieRepository->findByPidAndParent($myStoragePid, $parentCategoryId);

        $this->view->assignMultiple([
            'categories' => $categories
        ]);
    }
```

Repository

```
    /**
     * @param int $pid
     * @param int|null $parentCategoryId
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function findByPidAndParent(int $pid, $parentCategoryId)
    {
        $query = $this->createQuery();
        $query->getQuerySettings()->setRespectStoragePage(FALSE);
        $query->getQuerySettings()->setRespectSysLanguage(FALSE);
        $constraint[] =  $query->equals("pid", $pid);
        $constraint[] = $query->equals("parent", $parentCategoryId);
        return $query->matching($query->logicalAnd($constraint))->execute();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is not a TYPO3 question but a matter of a correct HTML structure and CSS.

First of all you should make sure to put the subcategories into their own sub-UL-LI-list. Then you should set the sub-UL to `display: none`;

Finally you can make use of the `:focus-within` pseudo class to set the sub-UL to `display: block` if the parent LI got focussed. This should work with a click as well as with tabbing through with the keyboard.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within

Comment: oh okay thank for the advice, this could work too in the case of if my subcategories have subcategories too ?

Comment: This should even work with nested UL/LI - you just have to make sure to use the CSS child combinator then, because you only want to make direct children visible and not each of them at once.

Comment: My page should be refreshed, so I have to redirect to the same page but with the subcategories appearing, so I adapted my code and I would like to filter by pid and by id of the parent but I can't create the query, I updated my message

Comment: This would generate a huge chain of "active" parent categories if users are clicking on them. And it would reload between each of the clicks. From a usability point of view this is a nightmare. So is there any plausible reason, why you need to do it this way?

Comment: BTW: findByPidAndParent is a method that makes Extbase "believe", there was a field pid_and_parent, so maybe you should change that method name to something else, that does not get resolved automatically or you should skip Extbase and go for a plain Doctrine query builder.